# How to mark question as solved?

Tags: discussion

they told me to mark the post as solved .. so i did that in the title.. seems not to be allowed.. but i asked and don't get an answer.. maybe help beginners by answering would be a nice feature. Can't finsd info on how to mark post as solved.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Read [My question was answered.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) please. Be a little bit patient as well. Even on a comment user may take a day to reply. Not everyone can dedicate that much time to help others for free.

Comment: if you want a platform you need to help people to get started. For free for sure. But as you already have.. this might get lost.. sorry

Comment: sorry.. i don't understand.. blender.se blender .meta.. i think i just leave you all with this 'forum'. I find it really users unfriendly.. chaotic.. and hard to use.

Comment: @Tuur sure we may come off as "hard to use" "super picky" and lots of other names, but that is just us trying to keep the site in some fashion of order. See [blender.​meta​.stackexchange.com](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com) is for question about https://blender.stackexchange.com (like your question here). https://blender.stackexchange.com (BSE for short) is the Q&A site for blender.

Comment: This is not a "forum", but a simple question and answers site. please take the [tour] to understand how the site work.

Comment: @Tuur It's a common misunderstanding, no worries. I hope you'll stick around, but if not, then that's okay too. Either way, good luck on your Blender endeavors :)

Comment: Thanks!... sorry.. i was a bit 'picky' myself i guess ... i'm back  then and will have a closer look to the 'rules' of usage of this site.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you mark a question as solved.

From the help center's [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) page:

> Accept it. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may [accept the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Then on the [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) page:

> Acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has been accepted by the original author of the question.
>
> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally.

You will find the accept button on the left of answers *to your questions* below the voting buttons.

[image: accept button on BSE]